# Calculating view height using screen width and aspect ratio not working on 1440p screen

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am programatically changing the height of a `ConstraintLayout` and its contained `ImageView` in a `RecyclerView`'s `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```kotlin
fun bind(model: CommunityOffer) {

    itemView.communityImageCl.requestLayout()
    itemView.communityImageIv.requestLayout()

    val aspectRatioSplit = model.mediaAspectRatio.split(":")
    val widthRatio = Integer.parseInt(aspectRatioSplit[0])
    val heightRatio = Integer.parseInt(aspectRatioSplit[1])

    if (model.mediaAspectRatio =="9:16" || model.mediaAspectRatio == "16:9"){
        communityImageIv.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
        communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = (communityImageCl.width / widthRatio) * heightRatio
        communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = (communityImageIv.width / widthRatio) * heightRatio
    } else if (widthRatio == heightRatio){
        communityImageIv.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
        communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = communityImageCl.width
        communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = communityImageIv.width
    } else{
        communityImageIv.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY
        communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = (communityImageCl.width / widthRatio) * heightRatio
        communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = (communityImageIv.width / widthRatio) * heightRatio
    }
}
```

View layout:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/communityImageCv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/communityImageCl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/communityImageIv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@color/alpha_grey" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

When the aspect ratio of an image, sent as metadata as a result of an API call, is conventional (16:9, 9:16, or 1:1), the image appears appropriately. However, a view whose aspect ratio is simply its dimensions (847:1280), gets scrunched into a square on ***1440p phones***, distorting the image[image]

Is there something wrong with my formula for calculating height? The debugger lists the height of the image view and constraint layout as zero, I assume because that's how they are set in xml. The width of the view must take up the whole screen and the aspect ration must be kept, even if it stretches the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I checked your screenshot, and can tell, that this distorted proportion is not exactly 1:1, which you can see here (I drew a red square over it):

[image: Imgur]

I think it might be that as you divide the width value by a big integer, you get very small integer, then you multiply it (as int it would be missing precision) so the result might be unexpected.

Simply cast it to float as you calculate it, the cast the result back to int, and it should work.

```
... ((communityImageCl.width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()
```

> P.S. I have never used Kotlin, so please someone edit above code if necessary.

Comment: My god. I can't believe it was a rounding error. Thank you so much.